# Aligning Text and Button in Toolbar

Tags: css, wordpress, toolbar

I just installed Foobar on my blog but the customer support hasn't responded yet after a few weeks to my query.

I'm basically applying this custom modification offered by them (http://codecanyon.net/item/foobar-wordpress-notification-bars/full_screen_preview/411466) to add a Like button to the toolbar at the top.

What I'm struggling with is to align some Text before the `<div id="social_target"></div>`, so that the text and the Likebutton will be aligned to look like "Like Us On Facebook! LIKEBUTTON".

Right now when I add text before the `<div id="social_target"></div>`, the text appears but the Likebutton appears underneath the text so it isn't visible at all.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how wordpress works and if you have access to the html code, but if yes, try putting the text inside a div and applying some css to it, something like this should work:

```
<div style="width: 400px;">
    <div style="float:left;">Like us on Facebook!</div>
    <div id="social_target"></div>
</div>
```

The value of the width is just a guess, you can adjust it.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to check:

Is the Div that your entire code (the text and the social_target div) being put into too small? If so, it'll push the Div onto the next line. You'll need to edit the size of the Div you're putting this stuff into.

Make sure you apply CSS to the Div so that it stays on the same line. Alternatively, you could use a span:

```
<span id="social_target"></span>
```

Otherwise, Divs will get pushed to a new line unless you specify something like:

```
#social_target { display:inline-block; }
```

or

```
#social_target { float:right (or left); }
```

Like Lucas has in his code above.